# Special Relativity: How to measure temporal distance?

Tags: special-relativity

I have a question about how to measure the temporal distance to an event, in order to calculate the spacetime interval.

If an object is at rest respect to me, at a distance X, Which is its temporal distance? If I suppose is the time I measure light comes from it to me, X/C , then spacetime interval is zero (S^2 = 0) ...but that means than all events at rest are a spacetime distance from me equal zero...and I suppose this is not correct.
How is temporal distance measured really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's draw the spacetime diagram showing you and the object. We'll assume that you are at the origin at the moment you make your measurement:

[image: Spacetime diagram]

I've drawn your worldline as the red line and the worldline of the object as the blue line. Then the interval between you and an event on the blue line is any arrow from you to the blue line. I've drawn three such lines as green arrows.

You ask about the temporal distance between you and the object, and I assume by that you mean $\Delta t = t_{object} - t_{you}$ so you can calculate the interval using:

$$ \Delta s^2 = -c^2\Delta t^2 + \Delta x^2 $$

The answer to this is that there is no unique answer. You can choose any point on the object's worldline and measure the interval between you and that point. I've drawn three such points, but obviously there are an infinite number of such points. You need to first choose what point on the object's worldline you want, then calculate the interval between you and that point.

The obvious point to use would be $(x, t=0)$. That is, if you and the object both had clocks that had been synchronised using some procedure such as [Einstein synchronisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation) then you would measure the interval between points that have the same time on both clocks. On my diagram that would be the horizontal green arrow.

Comment: Thanks, Jhon. So, if I am understanding it well, then, as the time interval is the difference between the two times (mine and the event), then, for objects that are at rest with me, there is no such temporary difference, and the space-time interval will simply be X. Is that right?

Comment: @Pedro yes, that would be the obvious interpretation of *temporal difference*

Answer (score 0):

send light signal that reflects there and gets back. If the time difference between sending and recieving signal is $t$ then the objects distance is $tc/2$, where $c$ is speed of light.